# Foreign Key Error value missing

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL and trying to assign a foreign key in a table but it shows an error depicting a value is missing in the primary key table. When I check for the missing value it shows the value does exist in the primary key column in the table.

Comment: if you use async for inserts, it may add PK value ATER it attemps to add FK

Comment: And what is the data type for this column? (and for the referred key)

Comment: Varchar(255) and the key is address. The primary key table contains the address which foreign key table depicts as missing.

Comment: Either you have leading/trailing space in (one of) your keyfields, or character set problems. Yet another good reason to avoid varchar/char colomns as (a part of) PKs FK2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lower caps issue within the column. All that was required was an update.